# Joining tables and displaying for comparision

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have three tables person, address and ID.

ID table has two columns ID1 and ID2. Iam trying to fetch data from person and address to compare like i displayed below.

When ID1 = Person.ID = Address.ID and ID2 = person.ID = Address.ID

```
________________________________________________________________________ 
name 1  age1    address1    city1   name2   age2    address2    city2
_________________________________________________________________________
abc      34    123 street    LA      abc    34     111 street   LA
xyz      22     New Street   DC      xyz    22     New Street   DC
___________________________________________________________________________
```

So basically i want to display first half of the above table based on ID1 and second half of the table with ID2.
How can i make this work I am new to queries any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you can, post your table structure. Table is not in a right order. Kindly make changes

Comment: You may get more help if you state what your original business problem is. For example, in a comment to Gordon's answer I speculate on what your business case may be. If that is indeed why you need this, you may not need to show data side-by-side; there are better ways to do these comparisons.

Comment: We are in the process of consolidating records, the ID table contains rowid's of the records which have been found as probable candidates. We want to get them in an excel in such a way that we can see all the records side by side, i know it sounds old school but that is the plan.

Comment: Why not do it all in the database? Comparing rows in two tables (when they should be identical or at least almost identical) is a common task, and there are well researched solutions, and Oracle has a package for this as well.

Comment: This is more for a not so technical audience, but i would like to know about  the Oracle package you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
select p1.name as name1, . . . 
from id join
     address a1
     on id.id1 = a1.id join
     person p1
     on id.id1 = p1.id join
     address a2
     on id.id2 = a2.id join
     person p2
     on id.id2 = p2.id;
```

Note:  Your data structure seems very strange.  Having a column called `id` shared between two different entities ("person" and "address") does not seem correct to me.

Comment: Speculating... perhaps they had the same information (id, name, address) in two parallel places and now they are consolidating, making sure it's done right? Same info in this system had ID1, in the other ID2... now they are consolidating?

Comment: Absolutely right, so we want to generate a report and compare them. The Id's in ID table are rowid's to fetch the data from those respective tables.